# R Leaflet HTML Formatting

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, leaflet

Using Labels along with addCircleMarkers I want to customize the format of labels displayed. This is achieved with HTML as follows.

```
labels <- sprintf(
"<div style = 'width: 170px; word-wrap: break-word;'> 
  <strong>%s</strong>
  <br/> %s%s: %s 
  <br/> Name: %s
  <br/> Name2: %s (%s)
  <br/> Name3: %s
</div>
", 
Title, subtitle, subtitle_1,value,name_1,name_2, units, Name3 , 
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

labels defined above is applied to addCirclueMarkers().

The leaflet map displayed shows the correct labels however the final %s for Name3 above is a long list of names. Unfortunately neither word-wrap: break-word nor word-wrap: break-all are working. The width is restricted to 170px but the text is not wrapping around the box.

What could be a fix to this problem.

I also tried passing the CSS parameters through labelOptions with no success.